# React Native Expo CLI: Map view crashed on stand alone app

Tags: react-native, expo

I’m developing an app using EXPO and this is my first experience of creating react native app.
I have just completed my project and every this working fine on local/Expo development tool. When I create standalone app of my project and go to MapView screen app crashes and when I again go to same screen map is showing but hang my app. Also I’m using google login, push notifications, deep linking all are working fine on Expo development tool but not working on standalone app.
Also I’m using SHA1 certificate from https://expo.io/accounts/myexpoaccount/projects/map-view-standalone-app/credentials and using in firebase and google.console.com

app.json

```
{

“expo”: {

"packagerOpts": {

  "config": "metro.config.js",

  "sourceExts": [

    "expo.ts",

    "expo.tsx",

    "expo.js",

    "expo.jsx",

    "ts",

    "tsx",

    "js",

    "jsx",

    "json",

    "wasm",

    "svg"

  ]

},

"scheme": "App",

"name": "App",

"slug": "App",

"version": "1.4.0",

"orientation": "portrait",

"icon": "./assets/icon.png",

"splash": {

  "image": "./assets/splash.png",

  "resizeMode": "cover",

  "backgroundColor": "#64985f"

},

"updates": {

  "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0

},

"assetBundlePatterns": [

  "**/*"

],

"ios": {

  "supportsTablet": true,

  "bundleIdentifier": "com.mypakagename",

  "config": {

    "googleSignIn": {

      "reservedClientId": "my-reservedClientId.apps.googleusercontent.com"

    },

    "googleMapsApiKey": "MY KEY"

  },

  "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist"

},

"android": {

  "adaptiveIcon": {

    "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",

    "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"

  },

  "package": "com.mypakagename",

  "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",

  "config": {

    "googleMaps": {

      "apiKey": "MY KEY"

    }

  }

},

"web": {

  "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"

},

"description": ""
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You eventually need to allow the Google Maps API in the google cloud console. This is a bit tricky, i faced the same problem. Test your app with following command:

```
expo start --no-dev
```

maybe expo will log a more precise error.
You can also try running it on an iOS device. You don't need to activate any API if you use Apple-Maps. If it works on iOS, you can be sure that you need to activate the right GoogleMaps-API on this site: https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/

EDIT:
If you are in the Google Cloud console, navigate to "APIs" on the left side and then choose "Maps SDK for Android" and activate it

Comment: Thanks for this amazing tip !

Comment: I'm having this crashing mapview issue. I have enabled all required APIs in google cloud console. any other changes?

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim does it work on Apple Devices with AppleMaps?

Comment: @jovan Yes, and I found that expo can not load MapView in production even images coming from outside do not show.